# assign href of anchor tag in javascript in display template

Tags: display-template

This is my HTML in display template. How can I assign value to href in javascript?

```
<span class="AnchorCls">
  <a id="link" href="#">_#=readMore=#_</a>
</span>
```

href should be like this:

```
 "/sites/Pages/BlogDetail.aspx?ID='" +newID + "'"
```

Answer (score 5):

In the display template make the following change:

```
var listItemID = ctx.CurrentItem.ListItemID;  //change as per your ID
var blogUrl = "/sites/Pages/BlogDetail.aspx?ID=";
var viewBlogUrl = blogUrl + listItemID;
```

HTML would be as below:

```
<a href="_#= viewBlogUrl =#_" target="_blank">Blog Title</a>
```